# How to start a paragraph from the middle of the page?

Tags: vertical-alignment

How to start a paragraph from the middle of the page, when something is already written in the first half of the page?

e.g.

```
\chapter*{Blabla}

\lipsum[1-2]

\gotohalf
\lipsum[3] <- the first line of this paragraph should start from the half of the text height (vertically)
```

EDIT
I don't think that minipage is a solution, because I don't want to modify the look of the chapter header.

Comment: By `middle` you mean precisely 0.5 of text height or you are talking in a general fashion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `\pagegoal`, `\pagetotal`

`\pagegoal` is a internal register that contains the height that needs filling, `\pagestotal` is the amount that is already filled.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Put a line in the middle of text height for testing
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(0,\dimexpr-\topmargin-1in %
                   -\headheight-\headsep
                   -.5\textheight\relax){%
      \line(1,0){\paperwidth}%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\gotohalf}{%
  \par
  \begingroup
    \dimen0=\pagegoal
    \advance\dimen0 by -\pagetotal
    \advance\dimen0 by -.5\textheight
    \ifdim\dimen0<0pt %
      % space left is smaller than half the text height
      \newpage
      \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
      \vspace*{.5\textheight}%  
      \vspace{-\parskip}%
    \else
      \vspace{\dimen0}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \chapter*{Blabla}
  \lipsum[1]

  \gotohalf
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

However there are severe limitations:

- LaTeX's output routine works asynchronous, the current values of `\pagegoal`/`\pagetotal` might not be too accurate. At the starting page of a chapter it might work.
- Stuff at the bottom (e.g. float objects) are not taken into account thus the middle moves up.

### Package `zref-savepos`

`\pdfsavepos` can be used to record the current position and is supported by many TeX compilers (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX; both modes PDF and DVI). The page position can be stored in the `.aux` file and used in the next LaTeX run. Thus at least two LaTeX runs are necessary.

Package `zref-savepos` adds a user interface to `\pdfsavepos`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Put a line in the middle of text height for testing
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(0,\dimexpr-\topmargin-1in %
                   -\headheight-\headsep
                   -.5\textheight\relax){%
      \line(1,0){\paperwidth}%
    }%
  }%  
}   

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

% Counter gotohalf helps creating unique label names for `\gotohalf
\newcounter{gotohalf}
\renewcommand*{\thegotohalf}{gotohalf\the\value{gotohalf}}
\newcommand*{\gotohalf}{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{gotohalf}%
  \zsaveposy{\thegotohalf}%
  \begingroup
    \dimen0=\dimexpr.5\textheight
      -\zposy{top}sp %
      +\zposy{\thegotohalf}sp %
      -\parskip
    \relax
    \ifdim\dimen0<0pt %
      \newpage
      \vspace*{\dimexpr.5\textheight-\topskip-\parskip\relax}%
    \else
      \kern\dimen0 %
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \zsaveposy{top}% one label at the top of a one page
                 % used as position reference for the top of textheight
  \chapter*{Blabla}
  \lipsum[1-2]

  \gotohalf
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I had to lecture, so I couldn't say “use `\pagetotal`”. `:-(` `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

Set a box as high as half the text height; some little adjustments must be added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-\topskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}% some backing up
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight][s]{\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
{\Large Title\\}
\vspace{4ex}
{\large Author\\}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{minipage}\par\nointerlineskip % pretend the previous box has no depth

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use the usual headers (or customized with `titlesec` or other package), just define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % to show page frames
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Chapter}{som}
 {%
  \cleardoublepage
  \vspace*{-\topskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}% some backing up
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight][s]{\textwidth}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\chapter*{#3}}
    {%
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\chapter{#3}}
       {\chapter[#2]{#3}}
    }%
  \begin{quotation}\small
 }
 {%
  \end{quotation}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \end{minipage}\par\nointerlineskip % pretend the previous box has no depth
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{Chapter}*{Introduction}
\lipsum[3]
\end{Chapter}

\lipsum

\begin{Chapter}{Title}
\label{x}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Chapter}

This is chapter~\ref{x}.

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that minipage works here, because I don't want to modify the chapter header.

Comment: @LionelDarondeau Use `titlesec` for typesetting the chapter title in a minipage.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the package [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1pt}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1pt}
\textblockorigin{0pt}{0pt} % start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\layout
\newpage
\chapter*{Bla}
This is some text.
% left margin: one inch (72pt) + \hoffset (0pt) + \oddsidemargin (62pt) = 134
% halfpos: \paperheight (794pt) / 2 = 397
% width: \textwidht (345pt)

\begin{textblock}{345}(134,397) % coordinates are computed with layout package
  \lipsum[1]
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

to produce this:
[image: absolute posistioned textbox]

If you need another position, you may play with the packages layout package, giving you the actual lengths.

HTH